# MsBuild and FxCop problems

Tags: msbuild, fxcop

I'm trying to make a build file to run with msbuild using cmd or jenkins build job.

The structure of the project is

[image: project structure]

the demo is here: [www.saramgsilva.com/wp7/sarasilvademo.rar](http://www.saramgsilva.com/wp7/sarasilvademo.rar)

Now i have 3 diferents ways to run fxcop, but i have problems in all.

**1)** In cmd go to the root file and then run

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe  .\SaraSilva.WP7.build /target:FxCop
```

this show a error: exit with code 128

**2)** In cmd go to the root file and then run

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe  .\SaraSilva.WP7C.build /target:FxCop
```

this doesn't create the buildartifacts\FxCop\FxCopAnalysis.xml file.

**3)** In cmd go to the root file and then run

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe  .\SaraSilva.WP7.build /target:TestWithCoverage
```

and

```
C:\SaraSilvaDemo\tools\FxCop-1.36\FxCopCmd.exe /file:C:\SaraSilvaDemo\buildartifacts /directory:C:\SaraSilvaDemo\buildartifacts\ /rule:C:\SaraSilvaDemo\tools\FxCop-1.36\Rules /out:C:\SaraSilvaDemo\buildartifacts\fxcop-result.xml
```

the result is:

> Microsoft (R) FxCop Command-Line Tool, Version 1.36 (9.0.30729.1)
>   Copyright (C) 2007 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Loaded DesignRules.dll... Loaded GlobalizationRules.dll... Loaded
>   InteroperabilityRules.dll... Loaded MobilityRules.dll... Loaded
>   NamingRules.dll... Loaded PerformanceRules.dll... Loaded
>   PortabilityRules.dll... Loaded SecurityRules.dll... Loaded
>   UsageRules.dll... Could not load Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit.dll. Could
>   not load GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP71.dll. Could not load
>   GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WP71.dll. Could not load
>   Microsoft.Phone.Controls.dll. Could not load
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll. Could not load
>   mscorlib.Extensions.dll. Could not load NLog.dll. Loaded
>   nunit.framework.dll... Loaded SaraSilva.WP7.AllTests.dll... Could not
>   load SaraSilva.WP7.App.dll. Could not load SaraSilva.WP7.Model.dll.
>   Could not load SaraSilva.WP7.SampleData.dll. Could not load
>   SaraSilva.WP7.SchedTask.dll. Could not load SaraSilva.WP7.Service.dll.
>   Loaded System.Core.dll... Could not load System.dll. Could not load
>   System.Windows.Browser.dll. Loaded System.Windows.dll... Could not
>   load System.Windows.Interactivity.dll. Could not load System.Xml.dll.
>   Could not load TombstoneHelper.dll. Initializing Introspection
>   engine... Could not resolve reference to System.Net. Analysis
>   Complete.
>
> NOTE: One or more referenced assemblies could not be found. Use the
>   '/directory' switch to specify additional assembly reference search
>   paths.
>
> - Analysis was not performed; at least one valid rules assembly and one valid target file must be specified.
> - 2 total analysis engine exceptions. Writing report to C:\SaraSilvaDemo\buildartifacts\fxcop-result.xml... Done.

I don´t know what to do :(

Answer (score 6):

The answer is to add the following switch to the command line to tell FxCop to search the GAC for assemblies:

```
/gac
```

Comment: I was getting the error message

    NOTE: One or more referenced assemblies could not be found. Use the '/directory' switch to specify additional assembly reference search paths.

This switch /gac fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm using FXCop 10.0 the error code you put are similiar:

> NOTE: One or more referenced assemblies could not be found. Use the '/directory' switch to specify additional assembly reference search paths.

hence, for my case I modified FxCopCmd.exe.config file and change AssemblyReferenceResolveMode from *StrongName* to *StrongNameIgnoringVersion*

This is to ensure that it doesn't trying to find specific version of referenced assemblies

also make sure in Visual Studio the dll properties is having Copy Local = True