# Code Analysis can't find reference, fails with 0 errors or warnings

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Build was failing with no errors, so I turned build output to diagnostic and discovered the problem was with code analysis:

> NOTE: One or more referenced assemblies could not be found. Use the '/directory' or '/reference' switch to specify additional assembly reference search paths.
>
> Code Analysis Complete -- 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
>
> Done executing task "CodeAnalysis" -- FAILED.
>   Done building target "RunCodeAnalysis" -- FAILED.

What's shown above is all the information given.

Included in this project is a referenced DLL. If I remove the reference (and code that uses it), code analysis stops failing. So it seems that for whatever reason code analysis can't find the referenced DLL.

The thing is - other than the failed code analysis, everything works. The DLL gets copied to bin and it runs fine. And in debug mode I can step through the code that calls the referenced DLL and it works as expected.

What could be causing code analysis to fail?

Comment: Have you tried to use the suggestion to just use a switch fro code analysis?

Comment: What version of VS are you using? 2010?

Comment: @JamesBlack - No, code analysis is automatically being called by Visual Studio 2012, so I don't know where the switches can be set.

I did add it as a reference path.

Comment: @Killingsworth - Visual Studio 2012

Comment: There should be a <codeanalysis> tag in the proj file that sets the path to the references. I would check to be sure that is correct.

Comment: How did you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using fxcop,
I answered this on this question [MsBuild and FxCop problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034922/msbuild-and-fxcop-problems/26628436#26628436)

another option is to make sure /gac arguments being used when running FxCopCmd.exe